# Pushing a controller from a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In essence what is the correct way of pushing a new view controller from a sub view of a navigation controller.

The issue being subviews of the navigation view don't inherit the `self.navigationController` (its `nil`)

The reason is I need separate controllers for the navigation bar view & the main view but both need to push new controllers.

I am willing to change this model if someone can tell me the correct way of doing this.

Also:

```
AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
[del.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Does not work as the delegates controller is `nil`.

Comment: Also:    
`
AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [del.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
`
does not work as the delegates controller is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a following category on UIView.

```
@interface UIView (GetUIViewController)
- (UIViewController *)viewController;
@end

@implementation UIView (GetUIViewController)

- (UIViewController *)viewController;
{
    id nextResponder = [self nextResponder];
    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        return nextResponder;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Now get the SuperView from the subView.

```
mySuperView = [mySubView superview];
```

Then call the method from category created.

```
mySuperViewController = [mySuperView viewController];
```

Now, using this viewController, you can access the navigationController.

I have not tried the above code and approach, but I hope it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat, does seem a little hacky though

Answer (score 1):

You may try two ways 
1.Use the superViewController's navigationController to push your viewController
2.Embed your current viewController in a NavigationController so that the navigationController won't be nil